# I can't dIsable touchpad by pressing f6 in Lenovo In Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu.

I want to disable my touchpad.

When I press <kbd>f6</kbd>, nothing happens. 
I think it need driver to install to fix this problem but how? I couldn't find anything

I don't want to disable it with commands or application I want to disable it Only with <kbd>f6</kbd> button (my laptop is Lenovo 81gb 15IKBN ideapad 320 )

Comment: Have you tried FN+F6?

Comment: Please only use tags that are directly related to your question. Thanks!

Comment: GabrielaGarcia Yeah nothing happen when i press it

Comment: Well I use Lenovo too and it worked without installing anything. Maybe the key is broken ? Try pressing it on certain application that need F6 as key, see if they register/recognize it.

Comment: Emmet          not its not broken it work on windows very well  but in ubuntu its not working

Comment: File a bug report on launchpad